# Creating UseEffect react hook which should go through JSON data and switch the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I'm trying to build filtering for job locations ("remote"/"in-person"/"hybrid") for my personal project and I was trying to troubleshoot it for quite some time (very new to programming). I am sure I made mistakes in my main fetchLocationData function and passing URLSearchParams but I am not gonna be surprised if there are more mistakes.....

```
      const fetchLocationData = async () => {
    const data = await getJobs();
    return data.json();
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    let condition = fetchLocationData();
    switch (jobCondition) {
      case 'On-site': condition.filter((con) => con.jobLocation === 'in_person');
        break;
      case 'Remote': condition.filter((con) => con.jobLocation === 'remote');
        break;
      case 'Hybrid': condition.filter((con) => con.jobLocation === 'hybrid');
        break;
      default:
        condition = null;
    }
    if (condition != null) {
      const params = new URLSearchParams({
        jobs: jobFilter || null,
        location: locationFilter || null,
        since: datePosted || null,
        conditions: `${condition.con}`,
      });
      history.push({ pathname: '/', search: `${params.toString()}` });
      return;
    }
    const params = new URLSearchParams({
      jobs: jobFilter || null,
      location: locationFilter || null,
      since: null,
      conditions: null,
    });
    history.push({ pathname: '/', search: `${params.toString()}` });
  }, [jobCondition]);
```

Comment: Why have you added two params at the end and what’s the issue you are facing?

Comment: I am not sure what your exact question is - if you are asking for a generic code review, I would suggest you go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead of stackoverflow. It is more likely you find someone to comment on your code there.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating switch statement you can somewhat optimize your code this way.

```
 let condition = fetchLocationData();
 let obj={'On-site':'in_person','Remote':'remote','Hybrid':'hybrid'}
 condition =condition.filter((con) => con.jobLocation === obj[jobCondition]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues with your code. I rewrote it and I think this is what you're looking for.

I did not know what kind of data `getJobs()` returned but I'm presuming it's an array of objects because you are filtering through it while trying return object data.

First thing first, move stuff out of useEffect. Create it's own function to handle all of functionality. Let's call it `jobFilterHandler`.

This `jobFilterHandler` will be wrapped in a useCallback. This is being done because while the function itself will be called in a useEffect, the data is being fetched and processed in this function. So we want this to return a memoized result to prevent unnecessary data fetching and re-renders.

I will add comments in the code to explain what it does.

```
    const jobFilterHandler = useCallback(async (jobCondition) => {
    // This function takes your filter_condition as an argument and is
    // asynchronous as marked above.

    const jobs = await getJobs(); // We retrieve the list of jobs from the API and wait for it.

    // Here we define the possible filter options to match with the raw data.
    const condition_options = {
      "On-site": "in_person",
      Remote: "remote",
      Hybrid: "hybrid"
    };

    // From the data we received, we filter the jobs that match our filter.
    const filtered_jobs = await jobs.filter(
      (job) => job.jobFilter === condition_options[jobCondition]
    );

    // If there are no filtered jobs, the function ends.
    if (!filtered_jobs) {
      return;
    }

    // Else the filtered jobs will be returned.
    return filtered_jobs;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // << here you need to write your code to fetch your jobCondition value >>
    jobFilterHandler(jobCondition).then((jobs) => {
      // << do whatever you want with the filtered jobs data here >>
      console.log(jobs);
    });
  }, [jobCondition, jobFilterHandler]);
```

Uncommented code here.

```
const jobFilterHandler = useCallback(async (filter_condition) => {
    const jobs = await getJobs();

    const condition_options = {
      "On-site": "in_person",
      Remote: "remote",
      Hybrid: "hybrid"
    };

    const filtered_jobs = await jobs.filter(
      (job) => job.jobFilter === condition_options[filter_condition]
    );

    if (!filtered_jobs) {
      return;
    }

    return filtered_jobs;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    jobFilterHandler(jobCondition).then((jobs) => {
      console.log(jobs);
    });
  }, [jobCondition, jobFilterHandler]);
```